# Update value in inner array

Tags: php, arrays

*This may be very simple question, sorry about my lack of knwoledge, and my stupidity...*

After adding Items to array,

```
$List[1] = array(
    'Id' => 1,
    'Text'=> 'First Value'
);
```

I need to change the value of an item in inner array,

```
foreach ($List as $item)
{
    $item['Text'] = 'Second Value';
}
```

But when i check Value remains same

```
foreach ($List as $item)
{
    echo $item['Text']; //prints 'First Value'
}
```

How to update the value to 'Second Value'?

Comment: It will change the entire array element, not just an item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either set it directly:

```
foreach ($List as $key => $item)
{
    $List[$key]['Text'] = 'Second Value';
}
```

Or set it by reference:

```
foreach ($List as &$item)
{
    $item['Text'] = 'Second Value';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a PHP-ish mystical Perl way to access the value, but I find it simpler to loop through the array and set the value directly.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($List); $i++)
{
    $List[$i] = 'Second Value';
}
```

Edit: Curiosity got the better of me. http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

```
foreach($List as &$item)
{
    $item = 'Second Value';
}
```

Notice the `&` which causes `$item` to be used by reference instead of by value.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($List as &$item)
{
    $item['Text'] = 'Second Value';
}
```